# Ordering the elements within facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have the order of x sorted on y column in the two facets. I tried to run this script but the order gets changed in facets.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Codds.png)

```
> new_data <- read.table("check.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
> new_data
  f     x     y stderr
1 A   one 0.308  0.003
2 A   two 0.305  0.004
3 A three 0.304  0.003
4 A  four 0.302  0.003
5 B   one 0.313  0.003
6 B three 0.310  0.003
7 B   two 0.308  0.003
8 B  five 0.307  0.004
> ggplot(new_data, aes(fct_reorder(x,y), y)) + geom_point(aes(color = f)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - 3 * stderr, ymax = y + 3 * stderr))+ coord_flip() +  facet_wrap(~ f,scales = "free_y",ncol = 1,strip.position = "right") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=90,hjust = 1), axis.text.y = element_text(size=9)) +theme_bw() +theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"),strip.text.y = element_text(size=8,face="bold"),legend.position = "none")
```

Can somebody help me how can I have in facet A: one two three four and in B facet: one three two five. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the code that follows I made x a factor with level and I changed the fct_reorder to ftc_rev

```
library(tidyverse)

new_data <- data.frame(f = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'), 
                       x = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one' , 'three', 'two', 'five'), 
                       y = c(0.308, 0.305, 0.304, 0.302, 0.313, 0.310, 0.308, 0.307), 
                       stderr = c(0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004)) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, 
                    levels = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'), 
                    ordered = T)) %>% 
  arrange(x)

ggplot(new_data, aes(fct_rev(x), y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = f)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - 3 * stderr, ymax = y + 3 * stderr))+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~ f,scales = "free_y",ncol = 1,strip.position = "right") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=90,hjust = 1), axis.text.y = element_text(size=9)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=8,face="bold"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: plot]